# Execlp vs Execl

Tags: c, execl

Is there any occasion in which is better to use `execl` instead of `execlp`?
I think that maybe when a program is in two different folders using `execlp` could lead to confusion but I don't know if it is the only case.
I ask because one could think that writing `execlp("ls", ...)` is easier than writing `execl("/bin/ls", ...)`.

Comment: If you don't mind running whatever arbitrary `ls` someone might have stuck in a `PATH` directory before `/bin/`, sure, go nuts with `execlp`. If you want consistent behavior, maybe be explicit?

Comment: In the case of `ls`, it's likely that a version will be found somewhere on `$PATH`.  For obscure programs you've written, it isn't clear that they're necessarily on `$PATH`.  So, one other risk with `execlp()` is that your program won't be found.  On the other hand, the problem with `execl()` is that you specify exactly where the program is to be found, and it will fail if it isn't there.  You have to balance the risks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Security

Looking programs up via `PATH` is convenient, but it can also be insecure. If a directory in a user's `PATH` is world writable, it's possible to inject a malicious program into the `PATH` lookup. This would affect `execlp` but not `execl`.

For example, if you had a `PATH` like `/foo/bar/bin:/home/you/bin:/usr/bin:/bin` and `/foo/bar/bin` was world writable, someone with access to that machine could copy a malicious program to `/foo/bar/bin/ls`. Then executing `ls` would run `/foo/bar/bin/ls` rather than `/bin/ls`. They'd be able to execute commands as you and gain greater access.

For this reason, it's often a good idea to refer to specific executables in known locations. Or to hard wire a secure `PATH` in the executable.

## Compatibility

[While there is a common set of Unix commands and features specified by POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/contents.html), many programs rely on extensions. If your program uses those extensions, grabbing the first one in the `PATH` might not be a good idea.

For example, here on OS X the installed utilities in `/bin` and `/usr/bin` are BSD-flavored. But I have GNU versions installed earlier in my `PATH`. A program designed to run on OS X would want to explicitly use, for example, `/bin/ls` or `/usr/bin/tar` to be sure they get a known version of those utilities.

```
$ /usr/bin/tar --version
bsdtar 2.8.3 - libarchive 2.8.3
$ tar --version
tar (GNU tar) 1.29
```

Answer (score 1):

Both `execl()` and `execlp()` work fine and similarly if your executables are in different folders or in the same folder, but you need to set the $PATH if different folders.

`execl()` is needed for executing executables (like `ls`) from **command line** as you can't go with `execlp()` in that case. I added a snapshot below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
        if (argc != 2) {
                printf("Usage Msg: ./a.out userdefined_executable\n");
                return;
        }
        
        //execl(argv[1], argv[1], NULL); // it works
        execlp(argv[1], argv[1], NULL); // it doesn't work

        return 0;
}

// Input will be like this, here "p1" is an user-defined executable.
// xyz@xyz:~/stack_overflow$ ./a.out p1
```